# Xamarin -- see generated Objective C code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

When I build an iOS app with Xamarin Studio, it always says it is "generating native code".

Can I see that native code anywhere?

Answer (score 5):

No and yes. Your question summary and details are different.

Xamarin.iOS generates **native assembly** code not ObjectiveC code (which is not native).

You can see the former (assembly) code if you use `-v -v -v -v` and look at the output (file) of the AOT compiler.